# Random number in random cell for 2048 game

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to create a random number in random cell in the 4x4 grid board. Basically I'm trying to write the 2048 game, but don't know how to get away with random number. Random number is supposed to be 2 and 4, with 90% is 2 and 10% is 4. This is my code for the grid I got:

```
int[][] board = new int[4][4];  //the size of the board is 4x4
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
String horizontal = "+----+----+----+----+";
String vertical = "\u2502";
//to print out the grid 4x4
System.out.print(horizontal + "\n"); // Top line            

for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) 
{
    System.out.print(vertical); // first column layout  
    for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) 
    {
        if (board[i][j] != 0) 
        {
            String sized = Integer.toString(board[i][j]);
            int check = 4 - sized.length();
            for (int k = 0; k < check; k++) 
            {
                System.out.print(" "); // Top line
            }
            System.out.print(board[i][j]);
        } else System.out.print("    ");
        if (j < 3) System.out.print(vertical);  
        else System.out.println(vertical);
    }
    System.out.print(horizontal + "\n"); // Bottom line
}
```

Comment: To create a number with 90% chance 2 and 10% chance 4, you need `int randomNumber = new Random().nextDouble() < 0.9 ?  2 : 4;`, then do what you want with that number.

Answer (score 2):

```
(Math.random() >= .9 ? 4 : 2)
```

This expression produces a random number 0 <= x < 1, then if x is between 0 and 0.9 (i.e. 90% probability), outputs 2, otherwise outputs 4 (10% probability).

Comment: i have to say I know it's simple but I'm in admiration of how neat that is!!

Comment: Wow, that's neat! Thanks a lot!